# How to make Firefox Developer Edition the default browser for a web app in NetBeans

Tags: firefox, netbeans, web-applications

Just installed Firefox developer edition alongside my 'normal' Firefox and like the look and features and would like to make the developer edition the default browser in NetBeans 8.2. It does not appear in the list of choices in NetBeans however. My 'normal' Firefox shows as does Chrome, Chromium, IE, etc. Just no developer edition of Firefox. Anyone know 'the trick'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Click Tools->Options-> Edit the Web Browser
   [image]
2. Click Add and find the firefox.exe
   [image]
3. You'll see it then.:)
   [image]

Comment: You know I've been in there a thousand times and it was right in front of my face. Thank you that worked.